# what is a usual topology for R

Tags: general-topology

i'm studying topology.
Let T be a usual topology for R(real) generated by usual metric.
first, i know that elements of T are open sets in R.
i wonder form of T(topology). 
Under given  condition, Can T have many form? or is T unique family?

Comment: *The* usual topology is generated by the open intervals $(a,b)$.

Comment: Then, Is T unique family of arbitrary union of {(a,b)}?

Comment: Yes. And, in fact, any open set is *countable* union of intervals.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on what   Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla said in a comment, “the usual metric” for $\Bbb R$ is the metric $$d(x,y) = \lvert x-y \rvert,$$ and “the usual topology” for $\Bbb R$ is the one where the basic open sets have the form $$(a,b) = \{ x\in \Bbb R\mid a < x < b \}.$$ (“Basic” here means that the open sets are unions of basic sets.)

There are many different possible topologies for $\Bbb R$, but only this one is called the “usual” topology.  There are many metrics one can put on $\Bbb R$, but only the $\lvert x-y\rvert $ metric is called the “usual” metric.

Comment: Oh!! Thank you for friendly explanation.

Answer (score 3):

In general it is possible to place more than one topology on $\mathbb R$. For example, the following topology (the trivial topology) is a perfectly fine topology for $\mathbb R$:
$$
\{\varnothing,\mathbb R\}.
$$
(You should verify that it satisfies the axioms for a topology.) Here's another example, the discrete topology, which consists of *all* subsets of $\mathbb R$:
$$
2^\mathbb R.
$$
However, the topology you have in mind -- the standard topology on $\mathbb R$, which has as a base the open intervals $(a,b)$ -- is uniquely defined, although there is more than one way to describe it.

Comment: If that is the case, then what is the difference between the usual topology and the [order topology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology) ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\Bbb R, d_{|.|})$ the *usual* (or *Eucledean*) *real metric space*, where $d_{|.|}$ denotes the *usual* (or *Eucledean*) *metric* $\Bbb R^2\mapsto\ \Bbb R_0^+$ and satisfies

$$\forall x,y \in \Bbb R : d_{|.|}(x,y):=|x-y|.$$

All real subsets that are $d_{|.|}$-*open* (i.e. open with the usual metric) can be collected in class

$$\mathcal T_{d_{|.|}}:=\{A\subseteq \Bbb R|A\space d_{|.|}-\rm open\}.$$
This class of real subsets forms a *topology induced by usual metric*, and the pair $(\Bbb R, \mathcal T_{d_{|.|}})$ is called *usual topological space*.

It is obvious that every open interval belongs to $\mathcal T_{d_{|.|}}$, for it is a $d_{|.|}$-open subset of $\Bbb R$.